# What is the proper way to release a socket after an ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE error occured in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have the problem that when I use a custom http agent, sockets are not released when an error occurs during the piping of the response.

It seems that Node.js isn't doing this on it's own. Thats why I tried to release it myself by destroying the response and the underlying socket but it didn't work. Nothing I tried worked expect destroying everything with `agent.destroy()`. This obviously can't be the solution because like this properly running sockets are getting destroyed.

That leads me to my question. What is the proper way to release a socket?

Following an example to reproduce it.

- Run the script below with `node index.js`
- Open http://localhost:3000/
- Cancel download

[image: Cancel download in chrome]

- You will see the socket remains occupied forever.

[image: Socket not being released]

If you call http://localhost:3000/small you see the behaviour I would expect to happen. Which is that the socket is getting released.

[image: Socket being release]

```js
const https = require("https");
const http = require("http");
const stream = require("stream");

const agent = new https.Agent({
    maxSockets: 20,
    maxFreeSockets: 10,
    keepAlive: true,
    keepAliveMsecs: 5000
});

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    let url = "https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.3/ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso?_ga=2.138549238.47332115.1635229845-1229485524.1607530765";

    if (req.url === "/small") {
        url = "https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.18.1/node-v14.18.1-x64.msi";
    }

    https.get(url, {
        agent
    }, (stream) => {
        stream.pipe(res);
    }).on("error", (e) => {
        console.error("Got error: " + e.message);
    });

    const cleanup = stream.finished(res, (error) => {
        if (error) {
            if (error.code === "ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE") {
                console.error("Pipeline ended non gracefully with no explicit error");

                // agent.destroy(); -- Don't want to do this!
                res.socket.destroy();
                res.destroy();
            }
        } else {
            console.info("Stream succeeded.");
        }

        cleanup();
    });

    logSockets();
});

const getSocketCountPerHost = (socketGroup) => {
    const regexp = /^:+|:+$/g;
    const sockets = agent[socketGroup];
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(sockets).map(([key, value]) => [key.replace(regexp, ""), Array.isArray(value) ? value.length : value]));
}

const logSockets = () => {
    const sockets = getSocketCountPerHost("sockets");
    const freeSockets = getSocketCountPerHost("freeSockets");
    console.info("httpsAgent.sockets", sockets);
    console.info("httpsAgent.freeSockets", freeSockets);
};

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
    setInterval(logSockets, 10_000)
});
```

Prerequisites:

- [Node.js v14.18.1](https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.18.1/node-v14.18.1-x64.msi) installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it myself. The key is to get the request from the `https.Agent` and destroy it if it gets closed prematurely.

```js
const clientRequest = https.get(url, {
    agent
}, (stream) => {
    stream.pipe(res);
}).on("error", (e) => {
    console.error("Got error: " + e.message);
});

const cleanup = stream.finished(res, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        if (error.code === "ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE") {
            console.error("Pipeline ended non gracefully with no explicit error");

            clientRequest.destroy();
        }
    } else {
        console.info("Stream succeeded.");
    }

    cleanup();
});
```